# STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION in C++

Tags: c++, stack

This is my code . It runs correctly when I dont use "POPSELF" array . But when I Use it , 
I receive the following error :
' 47 [main] QCL 1581244 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to QCL.exe.stackdump '

why It gives me such an error?

```
 // Declaring functions
 void license(); void Hamiltonian(double**,double*,double*,double*,double*,int,double&);
 void NEGF(complex<double>****,double**,double*,
        double*,double*,double*,double&,int,int,int,double,double);
// Global Variables
int main() {
    license();
    int n_Z ,n_E , n_K; double _Volt , _Temp ;
    GetParams Init ;  // Set Input Parameters
    Init.SetParams() ;
    n_Z = Init.Get_nZ() ;
    n_E = Init.Get_nE() ;
    n_K = Init.Get_nK() ;
    _Volt = Init.Get_Volt() ;
    _Temp = Init.Get_Temp() ;


    int ii=0 ,kk=0 ,xx=0; double *EnergyX ; double *PeriodX ;
    double *mstar; double *deltaU; double **Ham0;
    double *EpsDC; double *EpsAC; double dZ=0; ;
    EnergyX = new double [n_E] ; PeriodX = new double [n_Z];
    mstar = new double [n_Z] ; EpsDC = new double [n_Z];
    deltaU = new double [n_Z] ; EpsAC = new double [n_Z];
    Ham0 = new double *[n_Z];
    for(ii = 0; ii <n_Z; ii++)
    Ham0[ii] = new double[n_Z];

    Hamiltonian(Ham0,mstar,deltaU,EpsDC,EpsAC,n_Z,dZ) ;

    // NEGF
    complex<double> ****Gn= new complex<double> ***[n_Z];
    complex<double> ****POPSELF= new complex<double> ***[n_Z];
    for(ii=0;ii<n_Z;ii++)
        Gn[ii] = new complex<double> **[n_Z] ;
        POPSELF[ii] = new complex<double> **[n_Z] ;
        for(ii=0;ii<n_Z;ii++){
            for(kk=0;kk<n_Z;kk++){
                Gn[ii][kk] = new complex<double> *[n_K] ;
                POPSELF[ii][kk] = new complex<double> *[n_K] ;
            }
        }
        for(ii=0;ii<n_Z;ii++){
            for(kk=0;kk<n_Z;kk++){
                for(xx=0;xx<n_K;xx++){
                    Gn[ii][kk][xx]= new complex<double> [n_E] ;
                    POPSELF[ii][kk][xx]= new complex<double> [n_E] ;
                }
            }
        }

        NEGF(Gn,Ham0,mstar,EnergyX,PeriodX,deltaU,dZ,n_K,n_E,n_Z,_Volt,_Temp) ;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try looking at the stack dump.

Comment: In addition to what Raymond said, please use Google to find out more about the wonderful C++ standard library in general and the class `std::vector` in particular.

Comment: Cool! You're calculating hamiltonians. Those **** (pointer to pointer to pointer to pointer to complex double?) in NEGF and co. look a bit strange.

Comment: @  Rhythmic Fistman : Do you have any idea how to create and pass my 4D arrays in a proper way?

Comment: _Four_ levels of pointers? Are you on drugs?

Comment: Unlike restaurants, the quality of the code is not proportional to the number of stars it has.

Comment: @Borgleader: Yes, it is. It is an inverse proportionality.

Comment: What development environment are you using?

Comment: grounds_for_immediate_dismissal.cpp

Answer (score 3):

I would like to suggest a much better way to declare and use 4D arrays:

```
std::vector< complex<double> > POPSELF(n_Z*n_Z*n_K*n_E);
```

or at least:

```
complex<double> *POPSELF = new complex<double> [n_Z*n_Z*n_K*n_E];
```

then, being i,j,k,l the respective indices, you refer to the elements with:

```
POPSELF[l + k*n_E + j*n_E*n_K + i*n_E*n_K*n_Z ]
```

This is somehow long but with C++ you can encapsulate this stuff in a `Matrix4D` class and define `operator()` as:

```
complex<double> &operator()(int i, int j, int k, int l) {
    return POPSELF[l + k*n_E + j*n_E*n_K + i*n_E*n_K*n_Z ];
}
```

This is the correct approach when dealing with dynamic multidimensional matrices with scientific computing, being more efficient too - much more friendly than arrays of arrays (... of arrays of arrays!) with respect to caches and pre-fetchers.

Finally I've to say I've spotted an error in your code, but it's going to lead to a large memory leak, not to a segmentation fault I think: the for loop on ii is repeated nested, going to reallocate ii times all the array of arrays from the 2nd level, but holding a reference to the last one only.